# I want to design a user sign Up table

Tags: sql-server, database-design

I am designing a user sign up table in SQL Server where I have several tables including:

- Rolls table
- Country table
- City Table
- State Table
- User Table

I am having problem designing user table. Should I make Country, states, city columns as varchar or int? Should I make them as foreign keys if they are int?

[image]

This is my database diagram. Please help

Answer (score 0):

According to [database normalization forms](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/283878) you should make `Country, states, city` columns in your `USER` table as type `INT` with `Foreign key` constraint.

Answer (score 0):

If each user needs to be in one of the cities present in the City table, it will be enough to have a foreign key `city_id` in your user table and omit the state and province (if it means the same as state) altogether. State and country can then be derived from the city, and your database doesn't have any redundancies.

Comment: That means I only need **City_Id**  as foreign Key in my **User** table?

Comment: Yes, as long as all cities in which users live are required to be in the City table.